# touchpad firmware failed (code 24)

Tags: firmware, synaptics-touchpad

My touchpad won't work (error code 24). During the firmware update something went wrong and a message popped up that the firmware did not install. This is an HP dv6 7000 laptop running win10 (OEM is Win7).

> This device is not present, is not working properly, or does not have all its drivers installed. ([Code 24](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310123/error-codes-in-device-manager-in-windows))

I tried:

- installing four other firmware versions (16.2.14.0*, 18.0.7.54, 18.1.6.0, 19.0.24.0); none installed (one said it installed and then rebooted but did not work). (*from HP website and initially corrupted the firmware)
- changing driver version (16.5.3.3, 19.0.19.1)
- uninstalling all drivers to force the Windows driver
- removing the battery and power then holding the power button down
- uninstalling the touchpad from device manager
- uninstalling touchpad drivers from settings/devices/mouse&touchpad
- uninstalling all synaptics drivers from both systems/apps&features and from C:/, then searching through the registry and removing all ~30 synaptic entries
- combining the above

In general, when a firmware update fails then my understanding is that that device is no longer usable.

When I try to flash the drive with v19.0.24.0 I get this error (a driver is installed)

> A Synaptics Pointing device driver is required for reflashing. Please install a Synaptics driver version v15.1.6.0 or newer

or on v18.0.7.54 I get

> Reflash cannot find firmware updates for the device on this system

and on v 18.1.6.0 a dialog box appears that asks me to enter the Firmware but has no browse to function

When I check the touchpad settings in settings/devices/mouse&touchpad I get this msg (if drivers are installed); uninstalling and reinstalling as it says, does not work

> Unable to connect to the Synaptics Pointing Device Driver. If you have installed another PS/2 Pointing Device Driver please uninstall the Synaptics driver by clicking on the Yes button. You then need to reinstall your pointing device driver for your external device again.

There are quite a few posts that have the same firmware problem and some have the exact same laptop and tried the same things:

- This is the cleanest comparable case http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Synaptics-PS-2-Touchpad-Code-24/td-p/5605336
- In this case, it was due to a broken cable [Mouse Error Code 24. Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/466857/mouse-error-code-24-windows-7) (should I check if my ribbon burned?)
- In this thread from 2008, the user tired most everything and found no solution https://forums.techguy.org/threads/synaptics-touchpad-driver-problem.768956/page-3
- I fix it "My touchpad wont work" https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/250646/My+touchpad+wont+work+(device+could+not+migrated)+HELP
- On reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/5e8xrr/failed_synaptic_firmware_update_on_hp_dv6t7000/
- This post has the same laptop and same issues http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Touchpad-Firmware-Failed/td-p/2342695 resetting the driverthrough setting did not work for me
- This post updated the firmware for the same reason I did and got the same result http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Synaptics-touchpad-firmware-upgrade-failed-Now-not/td-p/5369577
- Here they were able to install the firmware after uninstalling divers http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/m6-1045dx-Flashed-Synaptics-Touchpad-Firmware-Now-my/td-p/2225129
- This one found a loose connector - has great images of troubleshooting and looks complete for process https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/70809-synaptics-touchpad-driver-failed-install-2.html?s=65b23c7b8e8dc16fd2cd65006d7bfdc7
- This post fixed code 24 -- they installed a new mouse pad http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19434175

Could just unplugging my touchpad and plugging it back in do something? I tried this and then got this error which on restart did not result in the touchpad working:

> This device cannot work properly until you restart your computer. To restart your computer now, click Restart Computer. ([Code 14](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310123/error-codes-in-device-manager-in-windows))

Is the fix a new touchpad? (a new/used one will be here Thur from ebay)

What is going on when the device bricks like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought a used touchpad off ebay and installed it. Touchpad works now. I think if the firmware update fails and the above steps don't revive it, then your touchpad is bricked and you need to replace it.

Some notes:

- Touchpads are glued to the case -- I have just tore them off with bruteforce but today I realized a hair dryer would soften the glue and make this less of an ape move
- There were no replacement touchpads for the dv6 laptop, by luck I found one used for $9. Whoever removed it did a nice job (glue looked untouched), which where I realized a hairdryer is a good move when I almost got mine out without tearing off the glue/sticky backing. My other laptop has replacement touchpads available - so this is hit and miss.
- The touchpad in the dv6 is permanently attached with molded plastic rivets (a dozen) holding the touchpad frame. I had to pop a little more than half these off (small screwdrivers wedged under edge and pry around each one until it pops) to get the frame to pull back far enough to rip out the touchpad. I then used superglue on each rivet (now missing the head) and then used a pair of flat screwdrivers to push the frame down around each rivet. The frame would sort of click onto each rivet and seemed to hold well enough until the glue dried.
- For $80 I could have bought a new topplate that included a new touchpad
- The good news: the top plate is easy to remove on the dv6, three minutes and it is off